# How to write proper partition by for this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, aggregate-functions, partition-by

We have data in this format.

```
item     club    dc     
1         2      100
1         3      100
1         4      200
1         5      200
1         6      200
1         7      300

2         3      100
2         4      200
2         5      200
2         6      200
```

What I need is, for each item dc wise count of all clubs.
Response should be:

```
item dc   club_count
1    100   2
1    200   3
1    300   1
2    100   1
2    200   3
```

I tried with basic `select item,dc, count(dc) over(partition by dc) from table` which is giving completely wrong answer. I also need order by cloub_count partion by items. So the final result should look like this:

```
item     dc   club_count
    1    200   3
    1    100   2
    1    300   1
    2    200   3
    2    100   1
```

Comment: Why not `COUNT` and `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Yeah that which ever works fine....I thought of partition by at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need a simple aggregation here, without window functions:

```sql
SELECT item, dc, COUNT(*) AS club_count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY item, dc
ORDER BY item, dc;
```

If you really wanted to do this using window functions, you could try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT item, dc, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY item, dc) club_count
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT DISTINCT item, dc, club_count
FROM cte
ORDER BY item, dc;
```

Comment: it worked !! Thank you so much. Is there any alternative using partition by you can share?

Comment: Window functions are honestly the wrong tool here, but I have included a query which uses them to arrive at the answer you want.

Comment: If the result set you described is really what you're after, you want `group by` with `count`. Yes, you CAN do it using an `over` clause, but doing so would be like going around your back to get to your elbow.